# An error occurred while installing active_shipping (0.9.13), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `bundle install` it gives the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing active_shipping (0.9.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install active_shipping -v '0.9.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But did install `gem install active_shipping -v '0.9.13'` before running `bundle install`. How could I fix it? Thanks!

```
xxxxxx:~/code/inventory$ gem install active_shipping -v '0.9.13'
Successfully installed active_shipping-0.9.13
1 gem installed
xxxxxx:~/code/inventory$ bundle install
Ignoring json-1.8.3 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine json --version 1.8.3
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:284: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Using rake (10.5.0) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.2) 
Using ZenTest (4.9.5) 
Using RubyInline (3.12.2) 
Using i18n (0.7.0) 
Using multi_json (1.11.3) 
Using activesupport (3.2.22.2) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.22.2) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.7) 
Using rack-cache (1.6.1) 
Using rack-test (0.6.3) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.2.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.22.2) 
Using mime-types (1.25.1) 
Using polyglot (0.3.5) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.22.2) 
Using active_utils (2.2.3) 
Using json (1.8.3) 
Using money (4.0.2) 
Using macaddr (1.0.0) 
Using uuid (2.3.7) 
Using active_shipping (0.9.13) from git://github.com/optoro/active_shipping.git (at master) 
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing active_shipping (0.9.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install active_shipping -v '0.9.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Yes but the bundler is trying to install from github not rubygem.org. Why dont you try to remove the github option in your Gemfile.

Comment: You are using a branch of the gem by `optoro`, not the main project by `Shopify`. This is why you are getting different results.